# Groupby and join in pandas dataframe for string column with newline character

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am performing a groupby in order to combine rows of a pandas dataframe where one of the columns has the same value.

I am able to do this with the use the the code `df_new= df.groupby(['Category'], as_index=False).agg(' '.join)` .
*Please see the modified dataframe as the output of this code.*

I have tried using different combinations of `"\n".join` but it has not worked properly.

Original:

```
    df.head()
    Name    Last    Loc     Category        
    [1]Tabby    buy     NJ      A
    [2]Tabby    buy     JP      B
    [3]Tabby    buy     JP      A
    [4]Tabby    sell    NJ      B
```

Modified:

```
    df.head()
    Name                Last        Loc     Category        
    [1]Tabby [3]Tabby   buy buy     NJ      A
    [2]Tabby [4]Tabby   buy sell    JP      B
```

I need the Name columns values to be delimited by newline (\n) instead of space to achieve the below result.

Expected:

```
    df.head()
    Name        Last        Loc     Category        
    [1]Tabby    buy buy     NJ      A
    [3]Tabby
    [2]Tabby    buy sell    JP      B
    [4]Tabby
```

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't accomplish what you want without have a new indexed lines (so '\n' doesn't work in DataFrame).

Easier solution:

```
df = df.sort_values('Category')
df['Last'] = df.groupby('Category')['Last'].transform(' '.join)
df.loc[df.duplicated('Category'), df.columns != 'Name'] = ''
```

```
>>> df
       Name      Last Loc Category
0  [1]Tabby   buy buy  NJ        A
2  [3]Tabby
1  [2]Tabby  buy sell  JP        B
3  [4]Tabby
```

```
>>> print(df.to_string(index=False))

    Name     Last Loc Category
[1]Tabby  buy buy  NJ        A
[3]Tabby
[2]Tabby buy sell  JP        B
[4]Tabby
```

---

**Old answer**

An alternative could be:

```
out = df.groupby('Category', as_index=False) \
        .agg({'Name': list, 'Last': ' '.join, 'Loc': 'first'}) \
        .explode('Name')
```

At this point, the output is:

```
>>> out
  Category      Name      Last Loc
0        A  [1]Tabby   buy buy  NJ
0        A  [3]Tabby   buy buy  NJ
1        B  [2]Tabby  buy sell  JP
1        B  [4]Tabby  buy sell  JP
```

Now you can use `.loc` to remove extra content:

```
out.loc[out.duplicated('Category'), out.columns != 'Name'] = ''
out = out[df.columns]
```

Final output:

```
>>> out
       Name      Last Loc Category
0  [1]Tabby   buy buy  NJ        A
0  [3]Tabby
1  [2]Tabby  buy sell  JP        B
1  [4]Tabby
```

Comment: Thanks. I was really looking for something that won't create new indexed lines, but if it cant be done, then your solution works as demonstrated. Appreciate your response.